# Parent page doesn't scroll when mouse over iframe

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I have a react page where I am including an `iframe` component. When my mouse is over the `iframe` component (on the iframe content) the parent page doesn't scroll. How can I make the parent page scrollable even when the mouse is on iframe content.

```
<iframe
    style={{width: '100%', overflow: 'visible', display: this.state.loader ? 'none' : 'block'}}
    ref='iframe'
    id={this.props.iframe.id}
    src={this.props.iframe.url}
    onLoad={() => this.iframeOnload()}
    width='100%'
    height='100%'
    scrolling='yes'
    frameBorder='0'
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you set the attribute `scrolling="yes"` this is why it is scroll-able.

try setting `scrolling="no"`

```
<iframe
        style={{width: '100%', overflow: 'visible', display: this.state.loader ? 'none' : 'block'}}
        ref='iframe'
        id={this.props.iframe.id}
        src={this.props.iframe.url}
        onLoad={() => this.iframeOnload()}
        width='100%'
        height='100%'
        scrolling='no'
        frameBorder='0'
 />
```